# How to make requests in SignalR Websockets in parallel? They are slow

Tags: performance, concurrency, websocket, signalr

I want to use websockets to load a lot of image tiles from my image server to fill a large mosaic image. Each tile is 512x512px, jpg compressed and takes 0.5 seconds to be generated on the server.

SignalR provides a good way to use websockets. However, when I do multiple requests (>100) to the server to generate and return all the tiles, it seems that those requests are processed in sequence, not in parallel.

Is there a way to get those tiles faster than in sequence?

I want to use websockets, since raw images cannot be downloaded fast enough: a browser only allows for 6 concurrent connections to a server.

My C# hub class:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public string GetTile(string url)
    {
        // simulate tile generation by sleep for 1 sec
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return "tile created";
    }
}
```

My javascript code:

```
        // create a custom SignalR Object
        var mySignalRHub = $.connection.myHub;
        mySignalRHub.client.echo = function (text) {
            console.info(text);
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { 
            var _i = 0;
            var _j = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < 43; j++) {
                    console.info("Asking for tile " + _j);
                    mySignalRHub.server.getTile("tileurl").done(function (data) {
                        console.log('tile ' + _i + ' created');
                        _i++;
                    });
                    _j++;
                }
            }
        });
```

The program will "Ask for" all tiles even before the first response is obtained.

Then, every second, a new response will be send to the client (instead of one second later, all responses will be returned almost simultaneously).

Why? And how could this process be parallelized?

Comment: " a browser only allows for 6 concurrent connections to a server" depends on browser

Comment: Your signalR connection can handle about 25 broadcasts per second, so I would look at how frequently you are able to broadcasts in any given second. If the server is taking .5 seconds to create a tile, are you broadcasting that tile immediately?  How many tiles are created in any given second? Theoretically, you could send up to 25 tiles per second. But there are a lot of unknowns without more code. Assuming base64 encoding and broadcasting the string to the client, your client then needs to decode the tile, which you will want to create web workers for performance.

Answer (score 0):

It must be using a single thread, and you're calling Thread.Sleep. If you want them to return as fast as possible, use a separate thread (e.g. BackgroundWorker) to process the request. A queue/dequeue mechanism would probably work well for this. Then as items clear the queue you can pump the response back with a client method instead of a basic "Get" request.

If possible, pass an array instead of sending a barrage of tiny requests. If you want it to load in "chunks" for UX/performance reasons, try larger chunks if performance is still an issue.